# ensure TOP (10) percent includes records from each date in range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to perfect an Audit methodology to gather 10 percent of records from the last week to they can be audited. I currently use a CROSS APPLY to get 10 percent for each office during the period, but most of those records are from the first 2 days. In order to improve audit I want to make sure that records for each day in the range are included in the 10 percent.

```
    SELECT   t1.PIC,   t1.TransID,   t1.ID,   t1.TranCode,  t1.Doc,  t1.TranDate,  t1.Operator,  t1.Office 
FROM [dbo].[Office]
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP (10) PERCENT d2.*
    FROM ##AUDIT AS d2
    WHERE d2.Office = [dbo].[Office].CodeValue
    ORDER BY d2.TransID
) AS t1
ORDER BY [dbo].[Office].CodeValue
```

This works great to get me 10 percent from each office, but I need to improve it.

Comment: Are your TransIDs issued sequentially?  Do you want to retrieve records randomly, or based on when they were created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't order by `TransId`, which is presumably incrementally assigned.  Instead, use a `where` to get the date period you want and then order randomly:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM [dbo].[Office] CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (10) PERCENT d2.*
      FROM ##AUDIT AS d2
      WHERE d2.Office = [dbo].[Office].CodeValue AND
            d2.tranDate >= dateadd(day, -7, cast(getdate() as date))
      ORDER BY newid()
     ) t1
```

Comment: Thank you. Presumably I can set the date range rather than using the last 7 days?

Comment: something like AND d2.TranDate >= @startdate

Comment: @DanielCooke . . . Yes, you can set the date range to whatever range you like.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative method, not using `top...percent`.  Assign row numbers pseudorandomly (using `newID`), starting over on each new `transdate`.  Use `ceiling(tot/10.0)` to get the number of records on each date that comprises at least 10% of the sample (e.g. 1 record if there were 10 or fewer records on that day, 2 records if there were between 11 and 20 records, etc), then select that many records from your initial table.

```
;with CTE as (
select tranDate, transID
    , count(transID) over (partition by tranDate) tot
    , row_number() over (partition by tranDate order by newid()) rn
from ##Audit)

select *
from CTE
where ceiling(tot/10.0) >= rn
```

You can modify the `partition by` portion of the query if you need to select 10% from each office, on each date, or other factors.

Comment: This is interesting. I am working on getting it integrated